# Android NDK doesn't find libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I'm making Android app and use NDK for some complex calculation, and I have problem with compiling it. I use Android 2.0 Preview 3b and NDK r10e.

I have problem with loading some normal libraries like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Error is `Cannot find`.
In `local.properities` I have `ndk.dir=F\:\\android-ndk-r10e`
In 'gradle.build' I have

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            multiDexEnabled = true
            applicationId = "lala.lala"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "lala"
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
}
```

This is Android.mk in jni folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := lala

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
                -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lala.c lalal.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And Application.mk:

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

Comment: do not use Android.mk and Application.mk: with gradle ... use `ldLibs` under `android.ndk` like `ldLibs "log", "m"` and `cFlags` like `cFlags "-DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL` ... the Android & Application mk will be genereted ... edit: at least it works in AS 1.5

Comment: Can you tell me excatly what to do? I have no experience with NDK and Gradle.

Comment: Error:No such property: cFlags for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.NdkConfig I have this problem

Comment: damn ... so it(as 2.0) it using new ndk plugin ... read this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental => `CFlags.add("-DCUSTOM_DEFINE")`

Comment: I have updated this but now have this: Exception com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Compiler exited with error code 1. And it cannot find libraries again

Comment: sorry i can't help you as I'm using STABLE version of AS(1.5) ... but there should be a link to the examples of new ndk plugin usage in my previous link